# JList no se me llena al abrir una ventana

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo dos ventanas, una que abro a partir de la otra.

Esta es `VistaAlbumesBuscar`:

```
public class VistaAlbumesBuscar extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

/**
 * Componentes de la ventana
 */
private Coordinador miCoordinador;
private JTextField campoTextoArtista, campoTextoAlbum;
private JLabel etiquetaArtista, etiquetaAlbum, etiquetaArtista2, etiquetaAlbum2, etiquetaCanciones;
private JSeparator separador;
private JButton botonModificar, botonEliminar, botonEliminar2, botonAdd;
private JList listaCanciones;
private DefaultListModel modeloLista;
private JScrollPane scrollListadoCanciones;
private JComboBox elegirAlbum, elegirArtista;
private DefaultComboBoxModel modeloCombo;
private Generador miGenerador;

/**
 * Iniciamos la ventana
 */
public VistaAlbumesBuscar() {
    iniciarVentana();
}

/**
 * Contenido de la ventana.
 */
private void iniciarVentana() {

    /*Propiedades Frame*/
    setTitle("Albums: Search");
    setBounds(100, 100, 353, 437);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);

    /*Etiqueta Artista*/
    etiquetaArtista = new JLabel("Artist:");
    etiquetaArtista.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    etiquetaArtista.setBounds(10, 11, 46, 14);
    getContentPane().add(etiquetaArtista);

    /*Etiqueta de Album*/
    etiquetaAlbum = new JLabel("Album:");
    etiquetaAlbum.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    etiquetaAlbum.setBounds(10, 36, 46, 14);
    getContentPane().add(etiquetaAlbum);

    /*Separador*/
    separador = new JSeparator();
    separador.setBounds(0, 76, 337, 2);
    getContentPane().add(separador);

    /*Etiqueta Artista II*/
    etiquetaArtista2 = new JLabel("Artist:");
    etiquetaArtista2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    etiquetaArtista2.setBounds(10, 89, 46, 14);
    getContentPane().add(etiquetaArtista2);

    /*Campo texto Artista*/
    campoTextoArtista = new JTextField();
    campoTextoArtista.setBounds(62, 89, 231, 20);
    getContentPane().add(campoTextoArtista);
    campoTextoArtista.setColumns(10);
    campoTextoArtista.setEditable(false);

    /*Etiqueta Album II*/
    etiquetaAlbum2 = new JLabel("Album:");
    etiquetaAlbum2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    etiquetaAlbum2.setBounds(10, 121, 46, 14);
    getContentPane().add(etiquetaAlbum2);

    /*Campo texto Album*/
    campoTextoAlbum = new JTextField();
    campoTextoAlbum.setBounds(62, 120, 231, 20);
    getContentPane().add(campoTextoAlbum);
    campoTextoAlbum.setColumns(10);

    /*Boton Modificar*/
    botonModificar = new JButton("Modify");
    botonModificar.setBounds(62, 151, 89, 23);
    botonModificar.addActionListener(this);
    getContentPane().add(botonModificar);

    /*Boton Eliminar*/
    botonEliminar = new JButton("Delete");
    botonEliminar.setBounds(161, 151, 89, 23);
    botonEliminar.addActionListener(this);
    getContentPane().add(botonEliminar);

    /*Etiqueta Canciones*/
    etiquetaCanciones = new JLabel("Tracks:");
    etiquetaCanciones.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    etiquetaCanciones.setBounds(10, 206, 76, 14);
    getContentPane().add(etiquetaCanciones);

    /*Lista de Canciones*/
    scrollListadoCanciones=new JScrollPane();
    listaCanciones = new JList();
    modeloLista=new DefaultListModel();
    scrollListadoCanciones.setBounds(10, 226, 210, 163);
    getContentPane().add(scrollListadoCanciones);
    scrollListadoCanciones.setViewportView(listaCanciones);

    /*Boton Eliminar II*/
    botonEliminar2 = new JButton("Delete");
    botonEliminar2.setBounds(226, 366, 101, 23);
    getContentPane().add(botonEliminar2);

    /*Boton Añadir*/
    botonAdd = new JButton("Add");
    botonAdd.setBounds(226, 332, 101, 23);
    botonAdd.addActionListener(this);
    getContentPane().add(botonAdd);

    /*Combo Artista*/
    elegirArtista = new JComboBox();
    modeloCombo = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    miGenerador=new Generador();
    elegirArtista.addActionListener(this);
    elegirArtista.setBounds(66, 10, 227, 20);
    getContentPane().add(elegirArtista);
    miGenerador.llenarComboArtistas(modeloCombo, elegirArtista);


    /*Combo Albumes*/
    elegirAlbum = new JComboBox();
    elegirAlbum.setBounds(66, 35, 227, 20);
    elegirAlbum.addActionListener(this);
    getContentPane().add(elegirAlbum);  
}

public void setCoordinador(Coordinador miCoordinador){
    this.miCoordinador=miCoordinador;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento) {
    if(evento.getSource()==elegirArtista){
        if(elegirArtista.getSelectedIndex()>0){
            miGenerador.llenarComboAlbumes(modeloCombo, elegirAlbum, elegirArtista);
            campoTextoArtista.setText((String)elegirArtista.getSelectedItem());

        }
    }

    if(evento.getSource()==elegirAlbum){
        campoTextoAlbum.setText((String)elegirAlbum.getSelectedItem());
    }

    if(elegirAlbum.getSelectedIndex()>=0){
        AlbumVO albumVO=new AlbumVO();
        AlbumDAO albumDAO=new AlbumDAO();

        albumVO.setNombreAlbum(campoTextoAlbum.getText());
        miGenerador.llenarListaCanciones(albumVO, modeloLista, listaCanciones, albumDAO);
    }

    if(evento.getSource()==botonModificar){
        try{
            AlbumVO albumVO=new AlbumVO();
            AlbumDAO albumDAO=new AlbumDAO();

            String nuevoNombreAlbum=campoTextoAlbum.getText();
            albumVO.setNombreAlbum(elegirAlbum.getSelectedItem().toString());
            albumDAO.modificarAlbum(albumVO, nuevoNombreAlbum);

        }catch(Exception excepcion){
            excepcion.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if(evento.getSource()==botonEliminar){
        int respuesta=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "¿Estás seguro de que deseas eliminar el Album?","Confirmación",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if(respuesta==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            AlbumDAO albumDAO=new AlbumDAO();
            AlbumVO albumVO=new AlbumVO();
            ArtistaDAO artistaDAO=new ArtistaDAO();
            ArtistaVO artistaVO=new ArtistaVO();

            artistaVO.setArtistName(campoTextoArtista.getText());
            albumVO.setNombreAlbum(campoTextoAlbum.getText());
            albumDAO.eliminarAlbum(artistaDAO, artistaVO, albumDAO, albumVO);
        }
    }

    if(evento.getSource()==botonAdd){
        VistaCancionesAdd ventanaCancionesAdd=new VistaCancionesAdd();

        ventanaCancionesAdd.setVisible(true);
        ventanaCancionesAdd.abrirVentanaCanciones(campoTextoArtista, campoTextoAlbum, modeloLista, listaCanciones);
    }
}

public void abrirVentana(JTextField campoTextoArtista2, DefaultListModel modeloLista, JList listadoAlbumes){

    miGenerador.llenarComboArtistas(modeloCombo, elegirArtista);
    miGenerador.llenarComboAlbumes(modeloCombo, elegirAlbum, elegirArtista);
    elegirArtista.setSelectedItem(campoTextoArtista2.getText());
    elegirAlbum.setSelectedItem(listadoAlbumes.getSelectedValue());
}

}
```

Y esta es `VistaCancionesAdd`:

```
public class VistaCancionesAdd extends JFrame{

private Coordinador miCoordinador;
private JTextField campoTextoArtistaCancion, campoTextoAlbumCancion, campoTextoCancion;
private JLabel etiquetaArtista, etiquetaAlbum, etiquetaCanciones, etiquetaCancion;
private JSeparator separador, separador2;
private JList listadoCanciones;
private DefaultListModel modeloListaCanciones;
private JScrollPane scrollListadoCanciones;
private JButton botonAdd, botonAdd2;
private Generador miGenerador;

/**
 * Iniciar la Ventana
 */
public VistaCancionesAdd() {
    iniciarVentana();
}

/**
 * Contenido de la ventana
 */
private void iniciarVentana() {

    /*Propiedades del Frame*/
    setTitle("Canciones: A\u00F1adir");
    setBounds(100, 100, 354, 374);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    /*Etiqueta Artista*/
    etiquetaArtista = new JLabel("Artista:");
    etiquetaArtista.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    etiquetaArtista.setBounds(10, 11, 46, 14);
    getContentPane().add(etiquetaArtista);

    /*Campo Texto Artista (No editable)*/
    campoTextoArtistaCancion = new JTextField();
    campoTextoArtistaCancion.setBounds(66, 10, 251, 20);
    getContentPane().add(campoTextoArtistaCancion);
    campoTextoArtistaCancion.setEditable(false);
    campoTextoArtistaCancion.setColumns(10);

    /*Etiqueta Album*/
    etiquetaAlbum = new JLabel("Album:");
    etiquetaAlbum.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    etiquetaAlbum.setBounds(10, 43, 46, 14);
    getContentPane().add(etiquetaAlbum);

    /*Campo texto Album (No editable)*/
    campoTextoAlbumCancion = new JTextField();
    campoTextoAlbumCancion.setBounds(66, 41, 251, 20);
    getContentPane().add(campoTextoAlbumCancion);
    campoTextoAlbumCancion.setEditable(false);
    campoTextoAlbumCancion.setColumns(10);

    /*Separador 1*/
    separador = new JSeparator();
    separador.setBounds(0, 70, 338, 2);
    getContentPane().add(separador);

    /*Etiqueta Canciones*/
    etiquetaCanciones = new JLabel("Canciones:");
    etiquetaCanciones.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    etiquetaCanciones.setBounds(10, 83, 74, 14);
    getContentPane().add(etiquetaCanciones);

    /*Listado Canciones*/
    scrollListadoCanciones=new JScrollPane();
    listadoCanciones = new JList();
    modeloListaCanciones=new DefaultListModel();
    scrollListadoCanciones.setBounds(10, 103, 216, 138);
    getContentPane().add(scrollListadoCanciones);
    scrollListadoCanciones.setViewportView(listadoCanciones);
    miGenerador=new Generador();

    /*Boton Añadir*/
    botonAdd = new JButton("Modificar");
    botonAdd.setBounds(239, 218, 89, 23);
    getContentPane().add(botonAdd);

    /*Separador 2*/
    separador2 = new JSeparator();
    separador2.setBounds(0, 262, 338, 2);
    getContentPane().add(separador2);

    /*Etiqueta Cancion*/
    etiquetaCancion = new JLabel("Canci\u00F3n:");
    etiquetaCancion.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    etiquetaCancion.setBounds(10, 293, 62, 14);
    getContentPane().add(etiquetaCancion);

    /*Campo Texto Cancion*/
    campoTextoCancion = new JTextField();
    campoTextoCancion.setBounds(82, 292, 144, 20);
    getContentPane().add(campoTextoCancion);
    campoTextoCancion.setColumns(10);

    /*Boton Añadir 2*/
    botonAdd2 = new JButton("A\u00F1adir");
    botonAdd2.setBounds(239, 291, 89, 23);
    getContentPane().add(botonAdd2);

}
public void setCoordinador(Coordinador miCoordinador){
    this.miCoordinador=miCoordinador;
}

public void abrirVentanaCanciones(JTextField campoTextoArtista, JTextField campoTextoAlbum, DefaultListModel modeloLista, JList listaCanciones){
    AlbumVO  albumVO=new AlbumVO();
    AlbumDAO albumDAO=new AlbumDAO();

    albumVO.setNombreAlbum(campoTextoAlbumCancion.getText());
    campoTextoArtistaCancion.setText(campoTextoArtista.getText());
    campoTextoAlbumCancion.setText(campoTextoAlbum.getText());
    miGenerador.llenarListaCanciones2(albumVO, modeloListaCanciones, listadoCanciones, albumDAO);

}
}
```

Pues yo abro `VistaCancionesAdd` a partir de `VistaAlbumesBuscar` y para ello uso estos métodos que se pueden ver dentro de las vistas.

El método que uso desde `VistaCancionesAdd`, que lo uso para que cuando se abra la ventana los `JTextField` estén llenos con cierto valor y lo mismo para la `JList`

```
public void abrirVentanaCanciones(JTextField campoTextoArtista, JTextField campoTextoAlbum, DefaultListModel modeloLista, JList listaCanciones){
    AlbumVO  albumVO=new AlbumVO();
    AlbumDAO albumDAO=new AlbumDAO();

    albumVO.setNombreAlbum(campoTextoAlbumCancion.getText());
    campoTextoArtistaCancion.setText(campoTextoArtista.getText());
    campoTextoAlbumCancion.setText(campoTextoAlbum.getText());
    miGenerador.llenarListaCanciones2(albumVO, modeloListaCanciones, listadoCanciones, albumDAO);

}
```

Y esta es la llamada que hago desde `VistaAlbumesBuscar`:

```
  if(evento.getSource()==botonAdd){
        VistaCancionesAdd ventanaCancionesAdd=new VistaCancionesAdd();

        ventanaCancionesAdd.setVisible(true);
        ventanaCancionesAdd.abrirVentanaCanciones(campoTextoArtista, campoTextoAlbum, modeloLista, listaCanciones);
    }
```

Este es el método `llenarListaCanciones2()`:

```
  public void llenarListaCanciones2(AlbumVO albumVO, DefaultListModel modeloListaCanciones,JList listadoCanciones, AlbumDAO albumDAO){

    Conexion conexion=new Conexion();
    //modeloLista.removeAllElements();
    try{
        String consultaSql="select name from track where albumid=?";
        PreparedStatement sqlNombreCancion=conexion.getConexion().prepareStatement(consultaSql);
        sqlNombreCancion.setInt(1, albumDAO.getIdAlbum(albumVO));
        ResultSet resultado=sqlNombreCancion.executeQuery();
        while(resultado.next()){
            modeloListaCanciones.addElement(resultado.getString("name"));
            listadoCanciones.setModel(modeloListaCanciones);
        }
        sqlNombreCancion.close();
        conexion.cerrarConexion();
    }catch(SQLException excepcion){
        excepcion.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
```

Este es el método `getIdAlbum()`

```
    public int getIdAlbum(AlbumVO albumVO){

    Conexion conexion=new Conexion();
    int id=0;

    try{
        String consultaSql="SELECT albumId from album where title=?";
        PreparedStatement sqlArtistaId=conexion.getConexion().prepareStatement(consultaSql);
        sqlArtistaId.setString(1, albumVO.getNombreAlbum());
        ResultSet resultado=sqlArtistaId.executeQuery();
        while(resultado.next()){
            id=resultado.getInt("albumid");
        }
        sqlArtistaId.close();
        conexion.cerrarConexion();
        return id;
    }catch(SQLException excepcion){
        excepcion.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
    }
```

Mi problema es que cuando abro `VistaCancionesAdd` no se llena la `JList` es mas, el que lo hace es el `JList` de `VistaAlbumesBuscar` y yo lo que quiero es que se llene el de `VistaCancionesAdd`.

Comment: Hay mucha información en tu pregunta pero el código no es funcional porque no incluyes partes importantes: clase Generador, Coordinador, AlbumVO, AlbumDAO

Comment: He añadido los métodos que son relevantes para realizar la acción que quiero, Coordinador simplemente todavía no tiene nada en las ventanas por lo tanto no es necesario incluirlo; AlbumVO es una clase con los Get y Set como indica el MVC, respecto a AlbumDAO ya he agregado una cosa, y Generador es lo mismo, tiene varios métodos que no tienen nada que ver con este problema, son métodos usados en otras clases.

Comment: Para poderte echar una mano necesito que publiques un programa ejecutable. Por desgracia no dispongo de tanto tiempo para buscar tu error sin ver correr el código.

Comment: Mi programa se compone de unas 15 clases con casi 1000 líneas de código, mas el conector de MySQL y una base de datos que tengo yo, si hay alguna forma de pasarte todo eso sin tener que ponerlo aquí, vale.

Comment: @NeoChiri no es necesario pasar toda la aplicacion, simplemente crea un programa más pequeño que tenga el mismo error para que podamos reproducirlo facilmente. Lo que se viene a llamar [MVCE](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).... :)

Comment: A ver que tenemos acá @NeoChiri :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu clase `VistaAlbumesBuscar` tienes el siguiente atributo:

```
private JList listaCanciones;
```

instanciado asi:

```
listaCanciones = new JList();
scrollListadoCanciones.setViewportView(listaCanciones);
```

dicho `JList` debe tomar valores (cargarse) cuando ocurre lo siguiente:

```
if(elegirAlbum.getSelectedIndex() >= 0){
    AlbumVO albumVO=new AlbumVO();
    AlbumDAO albumDAO=new AlbumDAO();
    albumVO.setNombreAlbum(campoTextoAlbum.getText());
    miGenerador.llenarListaCanciones(albumVO, modeloLista, listaCanciones, albumDAO);
}
```

entonces supongo que por lo que dices, este es el `JList` que sí se logra cargar con datos.

Luego, si presionas tu boton "Add" sucede lo siguiente:

```
if(evento.getSource()==botonAdd){
    VistaCancionesAdd ventanaCancionesAdd=new VistaCancionesAdd();
    ventanaCancionesAdd.setVisible(true);
    ventanaCancionesAdd.abrirVentanaCanciones(campoTextoArtista, campoTextoAlbum, modeloLista, listaCanciones);
}
```

pasas tu lista "cargada" hacia la otra ventana `VistaCancionesAdd`, misma que tiene también un atributo de tipo `JList` llamado `listadoCanciones` que se inicializa así

```
listadoCanciones = new JList();
modeloListaCanciones=new DefaultListModel();
scrollListadoCanciones.setBounds(10, 103, 216, 138);
getContentPane().add(scrollListadoCanciones);
scrollListadoCanciones.setViewportView(listadoCanciones);
```

Luego tienes tu metodo `abrirVentanaCanciones` que se define así:

```
public void abrirVentanaCanciones(JTextField campoTextoArtista, JTextField campoTextoAlbum, DefaultListModel modeloLista, JList listaCanciones){
    AlbumVO  albumVO = new AlbumVO();
    AlbumDAO albumDAO = new AlbumDAO();

    albumVO.setNombreAlbum(campoTextoAlbumCancion.getText());
    campoTextoArtistaCancion.setText(campoTextoArtista.getText());
    campoTextoAlbumCancion.setText(campoTextoAlbum.getText());
    miGenerador.llenarListaCanciones2(albumVO, modeloListaCanciones, listadoCanciones, albumDAO);

}
```

Pero si te fijas, aunque pasas los parámetros `modeloLista` y `listaCanciones` no haces nada con ellos en el método `abrirVentanaCanciones`, solo te causan confusión.
Si el método `llenarListaCanciones` de tu clase `VistaAlbumesBuscar` está funcionando de manera correcta, supongo que tu método `llenarListaCanciones2` es resultado de un copy/paste del primero,
verifica que estás cargando el modelo al `JList` correcto y elimina las redundancias que te comento. Luego de ello veamos que pasa.